# How to remove tabindex focus on div click using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular9, renderer

I have the following code. According to my requirement,

1. If I press tab from keyboard, then `<div>` element should be focused and `(click)` event should work - it is working fine currently
2. but if I click the same `<div>` element with mouse click, then this `<div>` element should not be focused and `(click)` event should work - here `<div>` element is focussing on first click only with the current code, don't know why ?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-k1vtmd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdivfocusout.directive.ts)

**html:**

```
<button>First</button> <br/>
<div tabindex="0" (click)="func();" (keyup.enter)="func();" appDivfocusout>Check Focus Out on Click</div> <br/>
<button>Second</button>
```

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  func(){
    console.log("test message");
  }
}
```

**directive.ts:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDivfocusout]'
})
export class DivfocusoutDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener('click',['$event'])
  onClick(e){
    this.el.nativeElement.style.outline = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: this.el.nativeElement.blur()..?

Comment: @MikeOne, Thanks for your response, but I am still getting the same behaviour.